# Showcase view not showing above the Dialog in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog, showcaseview

I am developing an app and I need to show showcase view on several case. In activity it is working fine. I have a dialog showing some recycler view data. In that dialog I need to show showcase overlay in first item of recycler view. I tried several libraries but none of them showing the showcase overlay above the dialog. ***Is there any other libraries for showing the showcase overlay above the dialog?***. I tried everything in GitHub and none of them works for dialog

Comment: Most of the show case view implemented activity level only. So, try to build overlay on your dialog.

Comment: so you are suggesting that I have to build custom overlay on dialog without an library ? @GobuCSG

Comment: Yeah, showcase libraries are almost outdated...  Very few libs are updated few years ago... and I haven't see like that